# How do I find a word recursively in all files and all directories

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

I am looking for a specific phrase in CentOS and I am not sure where and which file or even directory that has the file is. How can I do a complete recursive search on a phrase.
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

`man grep`
For this example, `grep -i -R "your phrase" directory`
`-i` means case insensitive
`-R` means recursively

If you don't know which directory, use / - but be prepared for it to take a long time.

Comment: as I said I have no idea about directory

Comment: updated with the root directory. It will take a long time though.

Comment: I did what you said but there are a lots of records..is there any way to save this to text file?

Comment: read about piping and redirects. > saves to a file, >> appends to a file, and | pipes to a process. So, in this case, `grep -i -R "your phrase" directory > /path/to/your/textfile` - also consider adding -l to the grep arguments if you just want a list of the files (as per @Richard Holloway

Comment: you can redirect the output to a file with `grep -i -R "your phrase" directory > myfile.txt`, or you could use less to view the result with `grep -i -R "your phrase" directory | less`

Comment: Make sure the file you are redirecting your output to isn't in the search path, or grep will find its own output. Recursion is only fun the first million times.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this one liner to get a list of all files in this folder and sub folders, containing the phrase "The phrase I am looking for".

```
  find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep "The phrase I am looking for" -l
```

Comment: Does this add any functionality over grep's recursive flag?

Comment: @James: No. I use it mainly to get the extra find functionality like specifying file name extensions (with -name "*.php" for example) and so on but in this example it adds nothing.

Comment: I'm also a pipe abuser. Once you're used to it it's hard to stop!

Comment: My servers cost enough money and do so little in return, what is a few extra processes here and there? :)

Answer (score 2):

[I would recommend `ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/).

Go to the uppermost level directory that you dare searching and then type:

`ack -a "Phrase"`

I don't really use grep anymore because of `ack`.

Comment: ack is great. You can install it on CentOS from the rpmforge repo. See http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge/Using for details on how to set this up.